# Enhanced WPF Menu

Tags: wpf, mvvm, wpf-controls, prism

Hello I'm developing a WPF Desktop application using MVVM and I'll like for my navigation module implement a menu like this one:

http://patterntap.com/tap/pattern/11543732834cb8a7ee18a51

I'm thinking to use a Menu control and change its appearance, but I don't know if I can apply this style to another control in a simpler fashion, also as I'm using MVVM I need a control that allows command binding.

Instead of using a traditional menu, is there another control that I could use to accomplish the same results?

Thanks and regards from Colombia!!!

Comment: It looks like a Horizontal StackPanel (or ListBox) and some custom dropdowns. You can create stuff like this using  "Control Templates"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would agree with Henk. You could make a custom `UserControl`. The `StackPanel` with `Orientation="Horizontal"` part for the menu item names and custom `ComboBox`es would be the easy bit. The tricker bit would be adjusting the default `ComboBox` `ControlTemplate` to your liking.

Here is a link to the deafult `ControlTemplate` for the `ComboBox` and an example... [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752094%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I think it looks like the menu you like might have two `ListBox`es in each drop down, but you could bind to their `ItemsControl` properties. Happy tweaking.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers, this is a good idea so let me try it and I'll share my progress!!!